# Dispatching chunks of work to backgroundworkers

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Using C#.

I have 100,000+ pieces of test data that need to have some calculations run with. My actual data set will be in the millions of pieces of data. The test data currently runs sequentially and takes about a minute to process. I want to split this work up and have backgroundworkers process back to back so I will hopefully get the processing done quicker.

What I have in mind is to do a foreach loop with the data and start a backgroundworker with each piece of data. I know I need to limit the number of bw's to three as I have 4 cores on this machine. I have done some testing with simple bw's but not three at the same time.

I have no idea how to go about this. How would one execute three background workers to process this data?

Comment: could anyone explain how bw related to number of cores ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker is designed for early learning work mostly. Maybe the odd alternative threading scenario. What you are doing sounds like a very advanced opeartion. You can still use BGW, but raw Threads, Tasks, Threadpools and the like would be better at this point.

There is also the general question if this operation can even be accelerated with Multithreading. I like to say "multithreading has to pick it's problems carefully". Pick it in the wrong scenario and you end with a programm that needs more memory, is more prone to errors and *slower* then a single BGW or sequential programm.

Your case could be one of the rare cases of a [pleasingly paralell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) operation. Or it could be mostly memory bound. Wich means you run into [Paralell slowdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Race_conditions,_mutual_exclusion,_synchronization,_and_parallel_slowdown) almost instantly. Resist atempts at hardcoding the number of threads. Usually you can leave that load-balancing work to a ThreadPool. To get a better answer you need to get a lot more specific.